# Using TeamCity to deploy 2 projects in the same solution to different servers

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

All,

I new to TeamCity and I'm have a configured teamcity for my .net 4.5 solution  and it builds fine.

However, my solution contains 3 projects. One of the projects is a web service and a web appication.

Please how do I configure Teamcity(MSBUILD) to deploy the webserivce project to a different server and the web web application project to a different server.

That is, after the successful server build, team city deploys the web application in the solution to Server A, while the web service is deployed to Server B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the WebDeploy operation via an MSBuild build step.  You will need a separate build step for each project.  Then [specify the WebDeploy server target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14264222/1453907) in your command line parameters with the `MsDeployServiceUrl` property.