# Msbuild ignores azure publish profile settings - Visual Studio 2015 - .Net 4.6.1

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I have 2 web API Project in my solution. One project is 4.5.1 and another project is 4.6.1.

**Project with .Net framework 4.5.1 builds p with the msbuild task with below parameters, and it properly publishes the code to azure. All Fine!!**

[image]

**Project with .Net framework 4.6.1 builds properly with the msbuild task with below parameters.**

[image]

**When build with above parameter the package is created not deployed to azure. See the log below.**

[image]

Please help, it is really strange. Only difference i see between the two web api solution is there **.Net framework version.**

Comment: Can you share the settings in the two publish profiles?

Comment: Those contains sensitive data of my site. Can I remove them and share?

Comment: Yes, remove the sensitive data and then share it.

Comment: wpp file solved my problem @EddieChen-MSFT. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use wpp files to xml peek your publish settings which will make a publish profile on the runtime of msbuild. use below xml snippet to create the wpp file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> 

  <!--
  When using this file you must supply /p:PublishSettingsFile as a parameter and /p:DeployOnBuild=true
  -->  
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" Exists('$(PublishSettingsFile)')">
    <!-- These must be declared outside of a Target because they impact the Import Project flow -->
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <DeployTarget>WebPublish</DeployTarget>

    <PipelineDependsOn>
      GetPublishPropertiesFromPublishSettings;
      $(PipelineDependsOn);
    </PipelineDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="GetPublishPropertiesFromPublishSettings" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" Exists('$(PublishSettingsFile)')">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <_BaseQuery>/publishData/publishProfile[@publishMethod='MSDeploy'][1]/</_BaseQuery>
      <!-- This value is not in the .publishSettings file and needs to be specified, it can be overridden with a cmd line parameter -->
      <!-- If you are using the Remote Agent then specify this as RemoteAgent -->
      <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <_MSDeployXPath Include="WebPublishMethod">
        <Query>$(_BaseQuery)@publishMethod</Query>
      </_MSDeployXPath>

      <_MSDeployXPath Include="MSDeployServiceURL">
        <Query>$(_BaseQuery)@publishUrl</Query>
      </_MSDeployXPath>

      <_MSDeployXPath Include="SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish">
        <Query>$(_BaseQuery)@destinationAppUrl</Query>
      </_MSDeployXPath>

      <_MSDeployXPath Include="DeployIisAppPath">
        <Query>$(_BaseQuery)@msdeploySite</Query>
      </_MSDeployXPath>

      <_MSDeployXPath Include="UserName">
        <Query>$(_BaseQuery)@userName</Query>
      </_MSDeployXPath>

      <_MSDeployXPath Include="Password">
        <Query>$(_BaseQuery)@userPWD</Query>
      </_MSDeployXPath>
    </ItemGroup>

    <XmlPeek XmlInputPath="$(PublishSettingsFile)"
             Query="%(_MSDeployXPath.Query)"
             Condition=" Exists('$(PublishSettingsFile)')">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="%(_MSDeployXPath.Identity)"/>
    </XmlPeek>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

create a wpp file with above xml code snippet and place it the same project where your csproj exists or if you are placing the wpp outside the csproj file folder to re-use in multiple projects then you need to add /p:WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile=

```
msbuild.exe MyProject /p:WebPublishPipelineCustomizeTargetFile=<path-to.targets-file>  /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishSettingsFile=<path-to-.publishsettings>
```

You can find more details on implementations @ http://sedodream.com/2013/06/05/HowToPublishAVSWebProjectWithAPublishSettingsFile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First suggest you manually use the `msbuild.exe` command to do the publish. This will narrow down the issue related to TFS side or not.

Also update your Azure SDK on the build agent to latest version([Azure SDK for .NET 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-sdk-dotnet-release-notes-3-0)).

Try to forcing the "PublishProfileRootFolder" parameter in your MSBuild argument. Details please refer this question: [MsBuild not finding publish profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840044/msbuild-not-finding-publish-profile)

Comment: I use publish profile from azure and pass it as argument to msbuild while building my source, so i dont know how much i can use PublishProfileRootFolder

Comment: @KarthikeyanVK Have you tried directly use msbuild command with the same parameter  for project with .Net framework 4.6.1, did this work properly. This will narrow down if the issue related to TFS side or build definition.

Comment: Hi @KarthikeyanVK, any update on this, have you figured it out?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12zq5FU8BxyjJIqYCR2tyeZADf2fDFaVq Both working and not working profile are shared

Comment: @KarthikeyanVK This is the publishsettings file, what's the publish profile? On the other hand, can you share the detail log on the OneDrive?

Comment: This is the one i downloaded from azure

Comment: @KarthikeyanVK Yes, you need to create a publish profile per to this publishseetings file (right click your project=>Publish=>Import profile)

Comment: I use publish profile downloaded from azure for all build and it works. I don’t want mess with my project settings. Hope you understand