# IIS WebDeploy using MS Build Fails with error MSB4044 -ConcatFullServiceUrlWithSiteName task

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msdeploy

In setting up a Jenkins deployment job, I kept running into this error when trying to deploy a Visual Studio 2012 Web project via the command line.

*error MSB4044: The "ConcatFullServiceUrlWithSiteName" task was not given a value for the required parameter "SiteAppName"*

For reference, here are the parameters that I used:

```
/p:Configuration=Release /t:Rebuild  /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /p:PublishProfile="DeployToDevServer" 
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://devmachine.server.com:8172/MsDeploy.axd 
/p:username=domainhere\adminuserhere /p:password=adminpasshere
```

Note: It would deploy just fine if I chose Publish... from inside the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much googling, and finally comparing a project that would deploy with the one that wouldn't, I finally figured it out after I opened the .csproj files with a text editor and compared them. 
In the project that worked, I found this section:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
```

And it had this line:

```
<DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site/sitenamehere</DeployIisAppPath>
```

I added this same line to the non-working project, changed the sitename, and it worked.
Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I added just the sitename as was configured in IIS and this worked for me (without 'Default Web Site')

Comment: You would only need to do `Default Web Site/sitenamehere` if `sitenamehere` is an application under `Default Web Site`. If you add a new website that is a sibling of `Default Web Site` then it would just be `sitenamehere`.

Answer (score 6):

You could pass this `DeployIisAppPath` as parameter to Jenkins, like this:
`p:DeployIisAppPath=Default Web Site/sitenamehere`
This would allow you to have different sitenames on different machines. While in your example (*with CSPROJ modification*) you would be obliged to have one IIS site name on all target machines

Comment: This is actually correct way to do it if you want to deploy via command line or TeamCity server. /p:DeployIISAppPath worked for me. THANK YOU!

Comment: This is a little unclear. This is an MSBuild parameter, not a Jenkins or TeamCity specific setting. Thanks!